# Deformation of nodal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper curve over a field $k$ with a node $P$. Suppose that $X \setminus \{P\}$ is smooth over $k$. Then there is a natural homomorphism
$$
T_X\mathsf{Def} = \mathop{\mathrm{Ext}}\nolimits_{\mathcal O_X}^1(\Omega_X, \mathcal O_X) \to H^0(X, \mathop{\mathscr{Ext}}\nolimits_{\mathcal O_X}^1(\Omega_X, \mathcal O_X)). 
$$
Show that $H^0(X, \mathop{\mathscr{Ext}}\nolimits_{\mathcal O_X}^1(\Omega_X, \mathcal O_X))$ can be identified with the first-order deformations of $P$.

Comment: I think you'll find this in any book on deformation of singularities — try [this](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr54.pdf).